# What tools and techniques are available for sanding without machinery?

Tags: wood, sanding, sander

I am planning on creating a table made out of recycled wood planks and I am wondering if it is too ambitious to hand sand the wood planks without the use of machinery.  I am on a budget and am wondering what types of tools would be best to hand sand wood?

Comment: Budgets typically have two factors: Money and time. If you have plenty of one, but not the other, it makes the decision that much easier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hand-plane before you sand. A good sharp plane and good technique produces a very nice finish. Only light sanding required after that.

Don't plane after sanding, the leftover grit will dull your blade.

Other than that, it's about elbow grease.